# Searching a file for Keyword,then outputting the entire sentence containing keyword

Tags: java, search

I am quite new to Java programming and I have encounter a problem. My problem is instead of returning a sentence from the text file, only the keyword is returned. Eg i entered " who had a good day today?" only "day" is returned. Let's say a text file contains "Paula had a good day today" My goal was to return "Paula had a good day today" and here is my code.

The issues are with the parseFile method and my if statement where i call the parseFile ()

```
 public static void parseFile(String s) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file = new File("today.txt");

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        final String lineFromFile = scanner.nextLine();
        if (lineFromFile.contains(s)) {
            // a match!
            System.out.println(s);
            break;
        }


    }
}

   this is my main 


public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException,
        FileNotFoundException {


    String[] keywords = { "day", "What book", "not going ", "okay"};

    boolean endloop = false;

    boolean found = false;

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = null;

    System.out.println("What's up?");
    do {
        System.out.print(" - ");
        input = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        for (String keyword: keywords) {
            if (input.contains(keyword)) {
                //System.out.println("Found keyword!"+ keyword);
                // TODO: You can optimize this
                parseFile(keyword);
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            System.out
                    .println("I am sorry I do not know");
        }

        break;
    }

    while (!input.equalsIgnoreCase("thanks"));
    System.out.println(" Have a good day!");

}
```

}
"today.txt" Contains
Paula is having a good day.
Carla asked What is a good book to read.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Not read the code too closely, but I don't see where `found` is ever set to `true`

Comment: It is true when the input is found..

Comment: Show me the line of code that sets it to `true`, coz I still can't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where you do

```
final String lineFromFile = scanner.nextLine();
        if (lineFromFile.contains(s)) {
            // a match!
            System.out.println(s);
            break;
        }
```

you print out "s" which is the thing you're looking for,
but you want to print out the line. which is "lineFromFile"
so you might want to do

```
final String lineFromFile = scanner.nextLine();
        if (lineFromFile.contains(s)) {
            // a match!
            System.out.println(lineFromFile);
            break;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are printing s which is that word used for searching. you should be printing the variable lineFromfile as it contains the value from file

```
public static void parseFile(String s) throws FileNotFoundException {
File file = new File("today.txt");

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    final String lineFromFile = scanner.nextLine();
    if (lineFromFile.contains(s)) {
        // a match!
        System.out.println(lineFromFile);
        break;
    }


}
```

}